# How to take a single row of data and convert to multiple rows for mysql database import

Tags: mysql, import, spreadsheet

I've searched a lot for answers, but decided to ask the great minds at Stackoverflow.

How can I take a single row of data, 10 columns and make it look as follows:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00 0000-00-00 00:00:00 1   3343    1   en-GB   1           15 South Peak LP    1   0       
0000-00-00 00:00:00 0000-00-00 00:00:00 35  3343    1   en-GB   1           853 Del Valle Dr    1   0       
0000-00-00 00:00:00 0000-00-00 00:00:00 3   3343    1   en-GB   1           Fallbrook   1   0       
0000-00-00 00:00:00 0000-00-00 00:00:00 39  3343    1   en-GB   1           CA  1   0       
0000-00-00 00:00:00 0000-00-00 00:00:00 2   3343    1   en-GB   1           92028   1   0       
0000-00-00 00:00:00 0000-00-00 00:00:00 48  3343    1   en-GB   1           San Diego   1   0       
0000-00-00 00:00:00 0000-00-00 00:00:00 5   3343    1   en-GB   1           7607231133  1   0
```

That is now 7 rows for the 1 row of data.
The third column represents the field item number for the data.
The forth column is the id number for the specific entry.

The original row of data looks like this:

```
3343    1   68  15 South Peak LP    853 Del Valle Dr    Fallbrook   CA  92028   San Diego   7607231133
```

Taking the row and doing a "Transpose" doesn't do the above. It merely rotates the data 90 degrees.
I need to take the data and create 7 rows, each with individual data.

If I can find a formula to place the data from "original" row columns D, E, F, G, H, I, J into individual rows of their own, then I can move the remaining data with other simple formulas.

To make this more complicated, the files with which I'm working are 550,000 rows. This means taking that single row and making it into 7 rows would make the file nearly 4 million rows...obviously I'll have to cut the file size down.

Does anybody know of a formula in OpenOffice Calc to produce the above?
OR...
Does anybody know of a way to import the rows of data into MySQL database using an OSD 550,000 line file to the table arranged as the 7 row example?

I can import an OSD into other tables. But this table has me baffled. There must be a way to get the single row of data into the database table.

Here is an example of the table in the database:

```
(`publishUp`, `publishDown`, `fid`, `sid`, `section`, `lang`, `enabled`, `params`, `options`, `baseData`, `approved`, `confirmed`, `createdTime`, `createdBy`, `createdIP`, `updatedTime`, `updatedBy`, `updatedIP`, `copy`, `editLimit`) VALUES
('0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 35, 2348, 1, 'en-GB', 1, '', '', '133 4Th St', 1, 0, '2013-02-23 02:22:00', 854, '76.28.168.75', '2013-02-23 02:51:45', 854, '76.28.168.75', 0, 1),
('0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 3, 2348, 1, 'en-GB', 1, '', '', 'Gonzales', 1, 0, '2013-02-23 02:22:00', 854, '76.28.168.75', '2013-02-23 02:51:45', 854, '76.28.168.75', 0, 1),
('0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 39, 2348, 1, 'en-GB', 1, '', '', '', 1, 0, '2013-02-23 02:22:00', 854, '76.28.168.75', '2013-02-23 02:51:45', 854, '76.28.168.75', 0, 1),
('0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 2, 2348, 1, 'en-GB', 1, '', '', '93926', 1, 0, '2013-02-23 02:22:00', 854, '76.28.168.75', '2013-02-23 02:51:45', 854, '76.28.168.75', 0, 1),
('0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 5, 2348, 1, 'en-GB', 1, '', '', '877-616 6144', 1, 0, '2013-02-23 02:22:00', 854, '76.28.168.75', '2013-02-23 02:51:45', 854, '76.28.168.75', 0, 1),
```

I hope this all make sense and that someone can really figure this out.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

To manage all Extract Transform Load processes I found useful Pentaho data integration application tool. It is based on Java and opensource. You can simply create transformation, chose file or DB input and then use transformation steps for Split fields and then use DB output to your MySQL db.

Comment: Vitorek - Thanks for the suggestion. I've never heard of the program but it may be worth investigating. In your experience, is this something the program can handle easily? And, once transformed, how long does it take to import into the db from this software? Or is that part of the process to import? Does the software only prepare a file that I would then import?

Comment: Pentaho uses java classes to establish database connection. You can set up more database connections and in different steps you can access different databases. It is possible to create files to import but it is also useful to make database updates.
Try to look at http://youtu.be/28f_qUo4U4c?t=2m13s

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not in a position to learn a new program, nor purchase one in "hopes" that it will do what I need. And I don't want to "extract" anything. I want to import into an existing db that already has thousands of correctly formatted entries. I can't afford to "experiment" with what is already working.

Comment: Yes, it is better to learn Pentaho in some sandbox. I would advice to use it if you process such imports more frequently. However it is intuitive and easy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

To flatten this structure using SQL you could easily do something like

```
select field1.sid, field1.enabled, field1.baseData, field35.baseData /* other fields...*/    

from
  (select sid, section, lang, enabled, params, options, baseData, approved, confirmed, createdTime, createdBy, createdIP, updatedTime, updatedBy, updatedIP, copy, editLimit from thetable where fid=1) field1

inner join  (select sid, section, lang, enabled, params, options, baseData, approved, confirmed, createdTime, createdBy, createdIP, updatedTime, updatedBy, updatedIP, copy, editLimit from thetable where fid=35) field35 on field35.sid = field1.sid

inner join  (select sid, section, lang, enabled, params, options, baseData, approved, confirmed, createdTime, createdBy, createdIP, updatedTime, updatedBy, updatedIP, copy, editLimit from thetable where fid=3) field3 on field3.sid = field1.sid

-- and so on for each field
```

1) Field fid=1 must always exist
2) You need to know the field ids in advance of writing query, which it looks like you do
3) You could outer join the subsequent fields to return the "parent" row if no other field records exist

Does that help at all?

Comment: Sambomartin - I think you are on to something, but not being a database programmer I'm not really following. In your "select", the most important field is fid, but there are 7 fid for each entry. I think I get that you are simply outlining and telling the db that fid 1 is field 1, and the others will follow with their own number as fid 1 is field2. I know this seem simple to you, but I can "look" as something and see how it's done, but I don't see the entire picture with just a breadcrumb. I get that you are trying to run an SQL query (right?) and using what you suggested.

Comment: ...but I've got 500,000 lines in 1 file with about 200 more that I need to address (each file will have at least 300,000 lines). Is what you are suggesting part of a php script that could read a CSV file and enter the data into the db directly? I have an old script that did that for another table arrangement, but I'm not savvy enough to figure out how to re-write that script.

Comment: I "had" replied at length to your suggestion. I actually filled out the fields you started, asking if what I'd done is everything you meant. For whatever reason, all that information was not saved. In short, then, are you suggesting I outline "each" entry with the 6 inner join, from and select lines of code? If so, that has to be repeated for "each" entry in 500,000 rows of the CSV file? Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: no, sorry thomas. a single query using the technique above will flatten your structure.  Each sub query returns the specific field for each `sid`. The outer query joins the fields by `sid`.  The result will be xxxx rows  `field1.sid, field1.baseData, field32.baseData, ...` you can then concatenate them together if you choose to get the string in your original post. does that make sense?

Comment: the would be a single query (allbeit with several subquery) written once to return all the data "flattened" out.

Comment: Sambomartin - so I could run this query (after completing the other 4 rows and the outside) and that would import the script into a "flattened" table? I would then have to export that flattened information as a CSV then import "that" file? Is that what you mean?

Comment: you simply need to extend my example to include sub queries for the additional fields (fids) you want, join using sid - the resultant query could then be used to create the file you need.

Comment: I'm a "newb" at trying to get things done in a db. In "my" head, you skipped over about 15 steps. Are you saying I need to create a new table, use your code to flatten the table (made of the imported csv file), then export (as CSV or ODS) so that the data has been rearranged in order to import into my desired table?

Comment: I'm guessing that your suggestion is to "flatten" the db. If that's what you meant, that won't work. I have more than 3,000 entries currently in the db. I'm not willing to disturb those. I need to figure out a method of import that will not alter what is already in the db/site. Taking a CSV (or ODS) that has 500,000 lines, converting each line to 7 lines (as in my example), then importing to the one table is what I'm seeking. Any thoughts?